se puede usar method override con un enlace en lugar del formulario
estoy trabajando con nodejs y el framework express, quiero utilizar delete y put, y dicen que para eso tengo que utilizar method-override, pero veo que por ejemplo para el metodo delete se usa un formulario yo lo que quiero es que quede mas o menos asi
<a href="books/delete/{{_id}}?_method=DELETE">eliminar</a>

hay alguna manera de hacerlo asi o es afuerza utlizando el formulario, aclaro lo anterior no me funciona
